# Attach 2-2-2-4 SER cable to bottom of ceiling joists

Tags: electrical

I am running 2-2-2-4 SER aluminum service cable perpendicular to overhead ceiling joists in an unfinished basement.  What do I use to attach the cable to the bottom edge of the ceiling joists?  I have been searching for cable staples with the plastic piece the shape of the cable, but I can't find any that are big enough, the largest I've found are GB 15/16th.

Comment: Note that you'll need "rat runs" - some sort of board that runs perpendicular to the joists - to meet code. This will prevent stress on the cable should somebody ever try to hang something from the cable - the weight will be borne by the board, not the cable itself.

Comment: @FreeMan - So then with that said, what do I use to keep the SER cable up between the boards?  I guess it would be something that would span the gap, assuming there is a board of sufficient thickness on each side of the cable.

Comment: See KMJ's answer for that. Basically, you nail/screw up something like a 1x3 or 1x4 then run the cable along that using the appropriate strapping. The 1x takes the weight of someone trying to hang something, instead of it bearing on the cable itself.

Comment: @FreeMan So to clarify, I attach the 1x3 or 1x4 perpendicular and to the bottom of the ceiling joists, then attach the SER cable to the board?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local electrical distributor should have two-hole straps in the appropriate size on the shelf. Mine stocks all the way up through 4" in half inch steps.

Also as properly pointed out by FreeMan you will need a runner board following your SER cable. This can be a 1x4 of the cheapest available wood, as it's only supporting the cable and is not structural.

Comment: Even the big box home improvement store will have a variety of 1- and 2-hole straps. They won't have every size...

Comment: Depends on the big box - I always have bad luck at Big Blue near here on small electrical parts.